# Отправка почты с файлом. PHP 7.1

Tags: php7, sendmail, laravel-5.6

Не могу сделать отправку файла на почту. Файл подгружается в форме, php версии 7.1, поэтому нет возможности использовать старые методы (не пропускает)

Вот пример последнего решения, которое дает ошибку:

> Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in....

```
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $mailto = 'weelman@mail.ru';
    $from_mail = 'info@zim-kolbasi.ru';
    $replyto = 'info@zim-kolbasi.ru';
    $from_name = 'Kolbaski';
    $message = 'Имя: '.$_POST['name'].'
Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'
Почта: '.$_POST['email'].'
Сообщение: '.$_POST['message'];
    $subject = 'Информация от посетителя Колбас';

    if($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) {
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])));
    }
    $EOL = "\r\n";
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($filename);
    $header = "From: " . $from_name . " <" . $from_mail . ">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . "\r\n";

    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

    $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";

    $header .= "<div style='color: black'>" . $message . "</div>\r\n";

    $header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename  . "\"" . $EOL . "";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $EOL . "";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $EOL . "";
    $header .= $content . $EOL;
    $header .= "--" . $uid . "--";
    var_dump($header);
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        echo "<script>alert('Success');</script>"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Failed');</script>";
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Вот зачем удалили проблемные участки? Теперь у вас, я думаю, будет уже не `Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in`

Answer (score 1):

Причина - множественный перевод строк в `additional_headers`.

По соображениям безопасности, несколько новых переводов строк подряд `\r\r, \r\0, \r\n\r\n, \n\n, \n\0` приводят к такой ошибке.

Следует "почистить" `additional_headers`: заменить переводы строк на одиночные.

В вашем случае, `\r\n\r\n` заменить на `\r\n\`. И используйте эту переменную только для заголовков. Вложенные файлы следует переместите в тело сообщения `$message`.

```
$from_name = 'Your name';
$from_mail = 'email@site.ru';
$mailto = 'email@site.ru';
$replyto = 'email@site.ru';

$subject = 'Информация от посетителя Колбас';

// Будем отправлять этот файл
$filename = __FILE__;
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));

$EOL = "\r\n";
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($filename);

// Заголовки
$header  = sprintf("From: %s <%s>\r\n", $from_name, $from_mail);
$header .= sprintf("Reply-To: %s\r\n", $replyto);

$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= sprintf("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"%s\"\r\n", $uid);


// HTML текст
$body = '<b>Текст сообщения</b>';

$message  = sprintf("--%s\r\n", $uid);
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $body . "\r\n";
$message .= sprintf("--%s\r\n", $uid);

// Аттач
$message .= sprintf("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"%s\"\r\n", $name);
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $EOL;
$message .= sprintf("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"%s\"\r\n\r\n", $name);
$message .= $content . "\r\n";
$message .= sprintf("--%s--", $uid);

var_dump(mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header));
```

Comment: изменил код, вот только на почту не приходит файл, а вот такое сообщение Сообщение: Msg msg beah--af033981e660d6567ccf9949cf0cc9c1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="38530328_433151437196201_7278755091702611968_n.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="38530328_433151437196201_7278755091702611968_n.jpg"
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/7QB8UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuM

Comment: ща попробую поправить

Comment: поставил старую версию кода